# Python: Remove Header top row from data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

So I have been working on a CSV data frame where I needed to transpose the data.
When I did this I have a line at the top that I am unable to remove.
It appears as such, and I just wish to remove the blank and the zero from this df.

> 

```html
                 0
Unit      Thousand
0-1           61.1
0-4            NaN
0-14         851.2
1-4          249.1
5-9          278.9
```

Attempted setting headers to none = None and index = None

EDIT: Unsure how best to display table

Comment: Ideally, `skiprows` during CSV import. Otherwise: `df = df.iloc[1:]`